# Calculating how symmetrical is a polygon drawn on a clock

Tags: geometry, symmetry

Say I have a polygon drawn on the face of a clock. Is there a way to quantify how symmetrical is the polygon and its subset polygons?

In the attached image I illustrate the intuition with quadrilateral, but ideally I'd like to generalize this to any kind of polygon.

Can anyone think of a clever way to solve this?

[image]

**EDIT:**

I have managed to solve this problem via computer where I simply express **the ratio between the number of total edges and polygons of the shape, with the number of distinct edges and polygons** of the shape.

So **for shape 1 of my example**, there are 4 kinds of edges and polygons ([0 3], [0 6], [0 3 6], and [0 3 6 9]). Each of these distinct elements each manifests 4 times in the shape, to make a total of 16 sub-polygons/edges that can be constructed from the whole. For instance, [0 3] appears by drawing clockwise from nodes 0 to 3, 3 to 6, 6 to 9, and 9 to 0.

Therefore, dividing the total number of polygons and edges (16) by the number of distinct polygons and edges (4), then dividing by the cardinality of the shape expresses what I am attempting to quantify quite well: **16/4 * 1/4 =1 (perfectly symmetrical).**

**In my 5th example,** in the polygon [0 1 3 7] there are 11 distinct edges and polygons, and 12 total edges and polygons ([0,6] can be drawn moving clockwise from 1 to 7, or from 7 to 1).
Therefore that polygon I get **11/12 * 1/4 = ~0.0303**

**This measure as far as I can tell perfectly captures the kind of measure I am after. With that being said, it is very computationally intensive.**

Perhaps there's a more clever way to calculate this without iterating?

Comment: If I move the vertices of #1 by a tiny random amount, it will look almost exactly the same, but none of the lengths will be equal. Do you intend for such a polygon to be less symmetric than #2 or #3 (which still have several pairs of equal diagonals, but look less like #1)?

Comment: Yes. It would be less symmetrical. A symmetry in this case must be perfect. Also note, that the strings can only be drawn on a clock with n faces.

Comment: This is one of the applications of group theory.  Rather than "more" or "less" symmetrical, group theory describes just how is an object symmetric.  Is is rotationally symmetric? does it have a reflexive symmetry?  A combination of both?  The most common groups that fit the describe the objects described above are the cyclic groups and the dihedral groups.

Comment: @DougM, I understand that point, but perhaps you can help me apply it.  For instance given the polygon [0 1 4 6 9 11] (picked numbers at random drawn on a 12-faced clock). How would I be able to derive the kinds of symmetrical groups without drawing it and counting it manually?

Comment: Your edit offers the kind of solution I imagined writing in an answer. Does it work for  polygons with more vertices. (I think you never need consider more than $6$ since the symmetry of a polygon should be the same as the symmetry of its complement.) Naive group theory won't work since from that perspective your #4 has no symmetries.

Comment: My edit works quite well, but I need to run this type of analysis on a massive dataset of polygons, and it's simply to expensive to run. Perhaps I'll start a new question asking specifically how to compute the number of unique vs. generic polygons in an efficient way.